# Null returns after the POST request

Tags: java

I wrote some Java wallet generation code and I use it for generating a crypto-currency wallet. The code is provided,

```
public synchronized WalletInfo generateAddress(GenerateWallet generateWallet) {

        final WalletInfo walletInfo = new WalletInfo();

        String walletName = generateWallet.getWalletName();

        String currencyName = generateWallet.getCurrencyName();

        WalletInfo walletInfoDb = iWalletInfoDao.getWalletInfoWithWalletNameAndCurrency(walletName, currencyName);

        if (walletInfoDb == null && genWalletMap.get(walletName) == null) {

            String currency = currencyName.toUpperCase();

            if (currency.equals("BITCOIN")) {

                final WalletManager walletManager = WalletManager.setupWallet(walletName);

                walletManager.addWalletSetupCompletedListener((wallet) -> {

                    Address address = wallet.currentReceiveAddress();
                    WalletInfo newWallet = createWalletInfo(walletName, currencyName, address.toString());

                    // set the properties of the walletInfo
                    // the instance is final and can work inside the lambda expression
                    walletInfo.setId(newWallet.getId());
                    walletInfo.setName(newWallet.getName());
                    walletInfo.setAddress(newWallet.getAddress());
                    walletInfo.setCurrency(newWallet.getCurrency());

                    walletMangersMap.put(newWallet.getId(), walletManager);
                    genWalletMap.remove(walletName);
                });

                genWalletMap.put(walletName, walletManager);
                return walletInfo;
            } else if (currency.equals("ETHEREUM")) {
                return walletInfo;
            } else {
                return walletInfo;
            }
        }

        return walletInfo;
    }
```

When I do a `POST` request using the `cURL`,

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"walletName": "Florence8","currencyName":"Bitcoin"}' http://localhost:8080/rest/wallet/generateAddress
```

I get `null` is the return,

```
{
  "id" : null,
  "name" : null,
  "address" : null,
  "currency" : null
}
```

While the entity is generated and still persisted in the MySQL.

I keep debugging and this is wired. The debugging doesn't follow `top-to-bottom` sequence of the code. The sequence of the debugging is like,

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I mean if the code comes to this line `walletManager.addWalletSetupCompletedListener((wallet)` then it should execute the operations inside, right?

Any sugesstion how do I get the entity back after rightfully persisted in the database?

Comment: Please cut down your code to a [mcve].

Comment: Why not just make `walletInfo` `final`?

Comment: I don't see any reason above that `walletInfo` can't be final. Remove the `= new WalletInfo()` as you're just overwriting it on the next line, and combine that onto one line `final WalletInfo walletInfo = iWalletInfoDao/*...*/;` Also note that it doesn't make much sense in a `if (walletInfo == null)` branch to call methods on `walletInfo`, as doing so will throw an NPE.

Comment: Would you like to have another look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Variable used in the lambda expression should be final or effectively final

The problem is that you're reassigning the value after you declare the variable - in fact, the first assignment is redundant, since you simply overwrite the value without using it.

So - make it effectively `final` by removing the first assignment:

```
WalletInfo walletInfo = iWalletInfoDao.getWalletInfoWithWalletNameAndCurrency(walletName, currencyName);
```

or *actually* `final`:

```
final WalletInfo walletInfo = iWalletInfoDao.get/*etc*/
```

---

Additionally, this condition:

```
if (walletInfo == null) {
```

is inverted: inside that block, you call methods on `walletInfo`; the calls would fail with `NullPointerException`, because `walletInfo` is null.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth noting he's also using `if (walletInfo == null) ... walletInfo.setName(walletName);`.

Comment: I see you both are right. Indeed, I have changed the question. Would you like to have another look? Btw, I created a new instance so not to get the `NullPointerException `